# If condition in JQuery for changing display

Tags: jquery, css

What I am wanting is when the loader's display goes to none then the script should work,
but the if condition is **not** working with **display == none**.

```
$(window).on('load', function () {
            $('.load').fadeOut('slow');
        });

        $(window).ready(function () {

            if ($('.load').css('display') == 'none') {
                $('.welcome').css({
                    transform: 'translateY(0px)',
                    opacity: '1',
                });
                $('.wel').css({
                    transform: 'translateY(0px)',
                    opacity: '1',
                });
            }
        })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you were to change `.fadeOut('slow');` to `.hide()` then your 2nd script will probably work.

It's not working because `.fadeOut` takes time before it's display-none.

Instead, use the callback option of `.fadeOut`:

```
$('.load').fadeOut('slow', function() {
    ... code that runs when fadeOut completed ...
```

```js
$(function() {
  $('.load').fadeOut('slow', function() {

    $('.welcome').css({
      transform: 'translateY(0px)',
      opacity: '1',
    });
    $('.wel').css({
      transform: 'translateY(0px)',
      opacity: '1',
    });
    
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class='load'>Loading...</div>
<div class='welcome' style='opacity:0'>Welcome</div>
```

---

If your welcome transition code *needs* to be somewhere else, you can trigger a custom event and listen for that.

Comment: but will ('.load') be displaying till the websites content loads up ?

Comment: You can still put the code in window.on(load) - see [onload vs doc ready](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3698200/window-onload-vs-document-ready)

Comment: yes, I tried the windows.on(load) and it worked